# How do I shade various regions defined by a hobby curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, hobby

Use the following code, I am able to generate the curve easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,>=latex, use Hobby shortcut]
        \draw[-] (0,3) .. (3,0) .. (4,-2);
        \draw[-] (4,-2) .. (5,0) .. (6,1);
        \draw[-] (6,1) -- (7,1);
        \draw[-] (7,1) .. (8,0) .. (11,-2);
        \draw[->,thick] (-.25,0) -- (12,0) node[above] {\footnotesize $x$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-3) -- (0,4) node[below right]{\footnotesize $f(x)$};
        \node[below] at (3,0) {\footnotesize $a$};
        \node[below] at (5,0) {\footnotesize $b$};
        \node[below] at (8,0) {\footnotesize $c$};
        \node[below] at (11,0) {\footnotesize $d$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My problem is I need to shade the regions bounded by f(x) and the x-axis over [0,b], [a,b], [b,c], and [c,d]. How do I achieve that with, say, red for the regions above the x-axis, and blue for the region below?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done by means of the `fillbetween` library which has been written for `pgfplots`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,>=latex, use Hobby shortcut]
        \pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}
        \draw[name path=f,-] (0,3) .. (3,0) .. (4,-2)
        -- (4,-2) .. (5,0) .. (6,1)
        -- (6,1) -- (7,1)
        -- (7,1) .. (8,0) .. (11,-2);
        \draw[->,thick] (-.25,0) -- (12,0) node[above] {\footnotesize $x$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-3) -- (0,4) node[below right]{\footnotesize $f(x)$};
        \path[name path=xaxis] (0,0) -- (11,0);

        \node[below] at (3,0) {\footnotesize $a$};
        \node[below] at (5,0) {\footnotesize $b$};
        \node[below] at (8,0) {\footnotesize $c$};
        \node[below] at (11,0) {\footnotesize $d$};

        \tikzfillbetween[
            of=f and xaxis,
            split,
            every even segment/.style={orange},
            every segment no 2/.style={top color=white,bottom color=orange},
        ]{red}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I concatenated your path segments to a single path in a trivial way. Then, I assigned `name path=f` to your path and generated a path for the x axis. Finally, I used `\tikzfillbetween` in order to compute + fill 4 paths, one for each of the intervals. The option(s) in curly braces (`{red}`) are applied to every path, the options inside of the square brackets determine how the paths are to be computed. In this case, path segments should be `split`ted and every second segment should be orange, and the one with index 2 should be shaded (note that the first has index 0).

The layering instructions `\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}` and `\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}` are merely helpful to place the filled areas behind the plot as such (the fill between layer has in initially configured as `on layer=pre main`).

Note that you need to load `\usepackage{pgfplots}` for this solution *and* you need `pgfplots` version 1.10. Details about the `fillbetween` library can be found in the pgfplots manual (compare Section Libraries - Fill between in  http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)

Comment: This is great, thanks! I do have a question, though. Why is the (appearance of) color in [0,a] different from that of [b,c]? How can they be made the same?

Comment: It is different because I configured `every segment no 2/.style={top color=white,bottom color=orange}`. Since indexing starts at 0, [b,c] is the segment with index 2. Uncommenting that item and/or more of the style options around it will make them the same.

Comment: I guess I wasn't terribly clear in my comment. It's not that I want the same color above and below, but the shading of the orange in the regions above isn't consistent. Did you do that intentionally?

Comment: Well, the shading was chosen intentionally, and the fact that [0,a] has no shading at all was also fully intentional. Only the third segment has a gradient at all... or did you mean something else with "consistent" (if so: consistent with what?). The first segment receives the style `every even segment` - and only that style - which states that it should be filled with `orange` (solid).